# Can I connect to Citrix as a site-to-site VPN?

Tags: vpn, citrix

Our application needs to automatically copy data from and to a customer's server. Usually we configure a site-to-site VPN between our network router and the customer's and then use existing tooling (SCP et al).

However, a new customer asked whether whether they can provide remote access to their files via Citrix. All I know about Citrix is desktop virtualisation. But is it also possible to use Citrix to set up a permanent tunnel that effectively works like a site-to-site VPN? Does the router (Linux) need special software to set this up?

The answer could be the Citrix product(s) that support this. I could tell the customer that if they have "Citrix xxx" we will be able to let our Linux-based router set up a permanent S2S tunnel to your Citrix xxx endpoint.

Comment: Which Citrix product? Citrix is a company, that's like saying "can I use Microsoft".  Citrix has file sharing, VPNs, and the app virtualization, depends on what you want to use.

Comment: The answer could be the Citrix product(s) that support this. I could tell the customer that if they have "Citrix xxx" we will be able to let our Linux-based router set up a permanent S2S tunnel to your Citrix xxx endpoint.

Comment: this might help... https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-gateway/12-1/vpn-user-config/configure-full-vpn-setup.html